# Show / Hide javascript function

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to show a div if the URL contains a parameter. 
I've run my JS on Chrome Console and it works just fine, but when I publish it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```html
<div class="alert alert-success" id="vendaPremium" style="display: none;">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="alert-icon">
          <i class="material-icons">check</i>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></span>
      </button>
      <b>Uhulll! Você acaba de se tornar cliente Meu Marketing Premium. Em breve entraremos em contato. \o/</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function sucessoCompra() {
  var alertaPagSeguro = window.location.href.split("?")[1];

  if (alertaPagSeguro === 'sucessoPagSeguro') {
    $('#vendaPremium').show();
  } else {
    $('#vendaPremium').hide();
  }
}
window.onload = sucessoCompra();
```

Comment: Remove the `()`. just assign `window.onload = successoCompra;`

Comment: Confirm somehow that you are using `jQuery` or another library having the `$` function.

Comment: @punund Since it works when she runs it by hand from the console, the library should be loaded.

Comment: @Barmar didn't work :-(
thx anyway

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: What does `console.log(alertaPagSeguro)` show?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    sucessoCompra();
});

function sucessoCompra() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var alertaPagSeguro = urlParams.get("query"); // Replace with name of your parameter

    if (alertaPagSeguro == "sucessoPagSeguro") {
        // Parameter equals string
        $("#vendaPremium").show();
    } else {
        // Parameter does not equal string, or doesn't exist
        $("#vendaPremium").hide();
    }
}
```

Problem could be because the script is executed before the JQuery library has been processed. If that's the issue, simply insert the `<script>` element (of your main code) below the JQuery Library.

Otherwise, what's the URL to the published webpage? Using my example above would probably be more efficient, as `URLSearchParams()` is [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility) - not on Internet Explorer however, so you may need a fallback.